# Passing a single record from an ActiveRecord model object into a param (or how to pass multiple fields in a param)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

I have a view displaying 'employee' records in a table where each table row haas a check_box_tag  to select that (row) employee record (the table is inside a form_tag).   The checkbox is passing an array of employee numbers to a method but I also need it to pass some of the other information from the record (first_name, last_name, etc) in the params.

Orignally this looked like (just passing an param with an array of employee numbers)

```
<% @employee_search.each do |e| %>
 <td><%= check_box_tag 'selected_subordinates[]', e.employee_number %></td>
 <td><%= e.employee_number %></td>
 <td><%= e.first_name %></td>
 <td><%= e.last_name %></td>
 ...
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure this was right, but I thought I should pass the entire record ('e') in the param:

```
<% @employee_search.each do |e %>
 <td><%= check_box_tag 'selected_subordinates[]', e %></td>
 <td><%= e.employee_number %></td>
 <td><%= e.first_name %></td>
 <td><%= e.last_name %></td>
 ...
<% end %>
```

The param array now looks like:

```
"selected_subordinates"=>["#<Employee:0xa946970>", "#<Employee:0xa946910>", "#<Employee:0xa9468b0>"]
```

I thought at this point I would be fine and just itterate through the objects in the param array referring to the record fields, but got an undefined method error:

```
params[:selected_subordinates].each do |s|
  puts s.last_name
end

undefined method `last_name' for "#<Employee:0xa946970>":String
```

I started wondering if for some reason the entire model object was passed instead of just one record from the object.   But, trying [0].last_name resulted in a different error.

```
params[:selected_subordinates].each do |s|
  puts s.last_name
end

undefined method `last_name' for 35:Fixnum
```

Maybe I should have been using the fields I need to build an array for the param - so the param would be an array of arrays?    I haven't had any luck so far trying to search for example of what to do when you need to setup a param array made of arrays, or pass a single model object record (and refer to it).

Thank You - Much Appreciated!

Comment: I guess I could do this and split the param value:   selected_subordinates[]', e.employee_number + ',' + e.first_name + ',' + e.last_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used `e` as the param, Rails was converting `e` to a String and passing that (you can't pass an object in an HTML form, right? Just values). When you saw `"#<Employee:0xa946970>"` in your params hash, it wasn't an Employee object, but instead a String with the contents of `#<Employee:0xa946970>` (which is what you get if you called `.to_s` on an Employee object).

Passing the ID gets you on the right track, but once you have the ID, you should look up the Employee with that ID from the database.

```
params[:selected_subordinates].each do |s|
  employee = Employee.find(s)
  puts employee.last_name
end
```

Of course, this loads them one at a time, so if you have a lot of checkboxes you could end up generating a large number of queries. You can also use the `find` method to find multiple objects based on an array of IDs:

```
employees = Employee.find(params[:selected_subordinates])
employees.each do |e|
  puts e.last_name
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah my first thought was to query each employee number but I didn't want to go down that road of a query for each selected item. So I can either use your method of a query against all checked items or do " selected_subordinates[]', e.employee_number + ',' + e.first_name + ',' + e.last_name" with a ".split(',')" in the controller against each array element (I did get that to work).  I think I'd feel less hacky with your method though. Thanks Again!